# Infinispan clustered lock performance does not improve with more nodes?

Tags: kotlin, kubernetes, locking, cluster-computing, infinispan

I have a piece of code that is essentially executing the following with Infinispan in embedded mode, using version `13.0.0` of the `-core` and `-clustered-lock` modules:

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var lockManager: ClusteredLockManager

    private fun getLock(lockName: String): ClusteredLock {
        lockManager.defineLock(lockName)
        return lockManager.get(lockName)
    }

    fun createSession(sessionId: String) {
        tryLockCounter.increment()

        logger.debugf("Trying to start session %s. trying to acquire lock", sessionId)
        Future.fromCompletionStage(getLock(sessionId).lock()).map {
            acquiredLockCounter.increment()
            logger.debugf("Starting session %s. Got lock", sessionId)
        }.onFailure {
            logger.errorf(it, "Failed to start session %s", sessionId)
        }
    }
```

I take this piece of code and deploy it to kubernetes. I then run it in six pods distributed over six nodes in the same region. The code exposes `createSession` with random Guids through an API. This API is called and creates sessions in chunks of 500, using a `k8s` service in front of the pods which means the load gets balanced over the pods. I notice that the execution time to acquire a lock grows linearly with the amount of sessions. In the beginning it's around 10ms, when there's about 20_000 sessions it takes about 100ms and the trend continues in a stable fashion.

I then take the same code and run it, but this time with twelve pods on twelve nodes. To my surprise I see that the performance characteristics are almost identical to when I had six pods. I've been digging in to the code but still haven't figured out why this is, I'm wondering if there's a good reason why infinispan here doesn't seem to perform better with more nodes?

For completeness the configuration of the locks are as follows:

```
        val global = GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder()
        global.addModule(ClusteredLockManagerConfigurationBuilder::class.java)
            .reliability(Reliability.AVAILABLE)
            .numOwner(1)
```

and looking at the code the clustered locks is using `DIST_SYNC` which should spread out the load of the cache onto the different nodes.

**UPDATE:**

The two counters in the code above are simply micrometer counters. It is through them and prometheus that I can see how the lock creation starts to slow down.

It's correctly observed that there's one lock created per session id, this is per design what we'd like. Our use case is that we want to ensure that a session is running in at least one place. Without going to deep into detail this can be achieved by ensuring that we at least have two pods that are trying to acquire the same lock. The Infinispan library is great in that it tells us directly when the lock holder dies without any additional extra chattiness between pods, which means that we have a "cheap" way of ensuring that execution of the session continues when one pod is removed.

After digging deeper into the code I found the following in `CacheNotifierImpl` in the core library:

```java
   private CompletionStage<Void> doNotifyModified(K key, V value, Metadata metadata, V previousValue,
         Metadata previousMetadata, boolean pre, InvocationContext ctx, FlagAffectedCommand command) {
      if (clusteringDependentLogic.running().commitType(command, ctx, extractSegment(command, key), false).isLocal()
            && (command == null || !command.hasAnyFlag(FlagBitSets.PUT_FOR_STATE_TRANSFER))) {
         EventImpl<K, V> e = EventImpl.createEvent(cache.wired(), CACHE_ENTRY_MODIFIED);
         boolean isLocalNodePrimaryOwner = isLocalNodePrimaryOwner(key);
         Object batchIdentifier = ctx.isInTxScope() ? null : Thread.currentThread();
         try {
            AggregateCompletionStage<Void> aggregateCompletionStage = null;
            for (CacheEntryListenerInvocation<K, V> listener : cacheEntryModifiedListeners) {
               // Need a wrapper per invocation since converter could modify the entry in it
               configureEvent(listener, e, key, value, metadata, pre, ctx, command, previousValue, previousMetadata);
               aggregateCompletionStage = composeStageIfNeeded(aggregateCompletionStage,
                     listener.invoke(new EventWrapper<>(key, e), isLocalNodePrimaryOwner));
            }
```

The lock library uses a clustered Listener on the entry modified event, and this one uses a filter to only notify when the key for the lock is modified. It seems to me the core library still has to check this condition on every registered listener, which of course becomes a very big list as the number of sessions grow. I suspect this to be the reason and if it is it would be really really awesome if the core library supported a kind of key filter so that it could use a hashmap for these listeners instead of going through a whole list with all listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are creating a clustered lock per session id. Is this what you need ? what is the acquiredLockCounter? We are about to deprecate the "lock" method in favour of "tryLock" with timeout since the lock method will block forever if the clustered lock is never acquired. Do you ever unlock the clustered lock in another piece of code? If you shared a complete reproducer of the code will be very helpful for us. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Karesti, thanks for a quick answer! I added the answers to the post above as I couldn't fit it into a comment. In addition, please don't deprecate the lock method :). 

It's a really powerful feature to be able to have these long running locks and to be able to wait for them indefinitely (especially since they don't thread block anyway), it would be a shame to see the feature lost.

Comment: Regarding the reproducer, I'll see what I can do. Because the initial setup is done on Kubernetes I can't reproduce it with just a github project, but I'll see if I can simply reproduce the linear increase in time in a local project

Comment: Clustered locks use listeners to be able to sync the locks when the topology or the lock is released, so you are running I believe into memory issues that cause your app to be slower as the clustered locks size grow. Clustered locks are not meant to be used this way, but for sync between infinispan nodes. We can't provide the listener feature you ask for that reason.

Comment: Instead of using locks, why aren't you using a cache and a clustered listener instead?

Comment: Sorry for having been unclear. Our scenario is that two or more pieces of code compete for the same resource (a session). Only one is allowed to have it at a time, so the lock is definitely the fitting construct for the scenario.

The core issue is that informing an update is an O(n) operation (where n is the amount of listeners) on every node, regardless of if these listeners are general (want all events) or only listen for a specific key. This is also why we can't roll our own cache, we would still need the clustered listener, which would also have this performance limitation.

Comment: Regarding memory usage, in the tests I have executed above a lot of memory is used, but utilization was still well within allowed bounds for the pods.

Comment: @karesti I believe Johan's point is that we should have only one listener for all the clustered locks in use on a node, and that listener should look up the lock in a HashMap (an O(1) operation), instead of CacheNotifierImpl invoking one ClusteredLockFilter for each lock (an O(n) operation).